# Como popular um array com os registros cadastrados do banco?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho uma box que mostra os registros que irão ser inseridos no banco de dados. Mas eu gostaria de fazer uma alteração nesses dados que foram inseridos. Assim queria saber como fazer os registros que estão na tabela do banco popularem a box.

Código:

```
<table border="0" align="center" height="100">
    <tr>
        <td>   
            <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
            <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
            <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300"></select>
            <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
            <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Ai ele cria um input e uma box' onde o input vai ser onde o usuário digita os dados que irão aparecer na box!

[Exemplo de inserindo na box](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/ht5b9xzk/)

Eu consegui criar um select que pega os dados e insere na box:

```
<table border="0" align="center" height="100">
    <tr>
        <td>   
            <font face="arial" align="center" valign="middle" color="blue" size="-1">PATRIMÔNIO</font><br>
            <input type="text" name="tx_patr" id="id_patr" maxlength="12" size="12" style="font-size:11; color:Black;" onkeypress="return SomenteNumero(event);" onkeyup="Mascara(this,Patri);" value="">
            <input type="button" onClick="move_patr_seri(this.form.tx_patr,this.form.cb_Patr);limpa_patr();" value=">>">
            <br>
            <select multiple size="7" name="cb_Patr" style="width:300">
            <?
                $w_querybusca="SELECT 
                                sai_cad_patr_seri.tx_num_patr
                                FROM 
                                sai_cad_patr_seri 
                                WHERE 
                                sai_cad_patr_seri.fk_seq_cara_peri = '$arr_w_param[17]'";     
                                $w_queryresultado=f_class_conecta_bd($w_querybusca);            

                while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado))
                {
                    print('<option value="'.$w_registro->fk_seq_cara_peri.'">'.trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr).'</option>'."\n");
                }
                ?>
                </select>                   
            <br>
            <input type="button" align="center" valign="middle" onClick="tira(this.form.cb_Patr)" value="<<">
            <br>
        </td>
```

Mas .. os dados que estão na box não se encontram no meu array de manipulação de dados (oque armazena os dados digitados pelo usuário), para mim inserir os dados populados da box no array eu deveria fazer como?

Inserir os dados no array:

```
function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino)
{
    var w_valor = Origem.value;
    var w_tipo;
    w_tipo = "S";

     if((Destino.name == "cb_Seri") && (Destino.options.length == w_cont))
        { return false;} 
     if((Destino.name == "cb_Patr") && (Destino.options.length == w_cont))
        { return false;}          

    if(Origem.name == "tx_patr")
        {
        w_tipo = "P";
        if (w_valor.length < 12 )
           {
           alert("Patrimônio obrigatório com 12 digitos!!");
           document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_patr.focus();
           return false;
           }
        }

    if (w_Cont_Qtde <=  w_Qtde_Peri - 1)
       {
        if ((v_patr.indexOf(w_tipo+w_valor) == -1) && (w_valor != ""))
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
            opt.text = w_valor ;
            opt.value = w_valor ;
            Destino.options.add(opt);

            v_patr[w_Cont_Qtde] = w_tipo + w_valor;             
            w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde + 1;
            if (Origem.name == "tx_patr"){ document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_patr.focus();}
            else { document.forms['sai_frm_incl_patr_seri'].tx_seri.focus();    }       
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Patrimônio OU Serial já existe OU não é válido!");
            return true;
        }
      }

    else
    if(w_ver == 1){
        alert("Quantidade atingida!");
        if(confirm("Deseja inserir a mesma quantidade para ambos?") == true)
        {
            w_cont = w_Qtde_Peri;
            w_ver = 0;
            w_Qtde_Peri = w_Qtde_Peri + w_Qtde_Peri;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
        alert("Quantidade informada ja Incluida !!!");
   return true; 
}
```

O array é o `v_patr`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Armazene em uma variável os registros pegos do banco e dê um `echo` dentro do *script* também, escrevendo-o como você fez com o *HTML*.

Na listagem...

```
$objs = array();
while($w_registro = pg_fetch_object($w_queryresultado)) {
   $objs[$w_registro->fk_seq_cara_peri] = trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr);
   print('<option value="'.$w_registro->fk_seq_cara_peri.'">'.trim($w_registro->tx_num_patr).'</option>'."\n");
}
```

E na parte do script...

```
<script>
<?php
$v_patr = '';
foreach ($objs as $obk => $obn){
  $v_patr .= "'{$obk}{$obn}', ";
}
$v_patr = trim($v_patr, ', ');

echo 'v_patr = ['.$v_patr.'];'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'w_Cont_Qtde  = '.count($objs).';'.PHP_EOL;
?>
function move_patr_seri(Origem, Destino)
{
.
.
.
```

Não entendi muito bem sua regra, mas é só adapta-lo da forma que te atende melhor.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que precisava @KaduAmaral, agora em meu caso só necessito popular os campos com os dados!